# Android Async Http Client - Getting POST Url

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, http-post, loopj

Im using the [LoopJ - Async Http Client For Android](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to perform some async post requests to login to a website. Im using the AsyncHttpRequestHandlers to keep the process async and seperate from the Android UI thread.

I want to get the page URL after the request - usually the HTTP Response is 200, with ocassional 3xx responses, in between the onSuccess method. Im unsure how I get access to the page URL.

Ive seen various solutions that use synchronous or deprecated methods

- [Getting URL after a redirect using HttpClient.Execute(HttpGet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341475/getting-url-after-a-redirect-using-httpclient-executehttpget)  - *Synchronous*
- [Obtaining URL from http response when no location header is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074400/obtaining-url-from-http-response-when-no-location-header-is-sent) - *Synchronous*
- [Apache HttpClient: Location of redirected URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624694/apache-httpclient-location-of-redirected-urls) - *Deprecated*
- [HttpClient 4 - How to capture last redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20508342/1725588) - *Deprecated (Redirect Strategy)*

---

### Current Code Structure

```
static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

static {
    client.setUserAgent(USER_AGENT);
    client.setEnableRedirects(true);
} 

public static void login(String user, String password) {
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("login", user);
    params.put("password", password);

    client.post(LOGIN_URL, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            //Get Final Url Of Page
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            //Handle Failure
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a possible solution that I can easily integrate with this structure, whilst retrieving the current page url once the post request has been successful?

Comment: Which is the question? What's your problem?

Comment: Im wanting to find the URL of the page once the post request has returned successful. Ive attempted similar solutions, that I've linked to, which finds a list of redirected URLs or the last know URL. - I've updated the question now to try reflect this question better

Comment: Have you tried setting `client.setEnableRedirects(true)`?

Comment: @Enrichman Yes, apologies that is part of the code I've omitted